# How to make Yii CButtonColumn custom button global?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I was using Yii's CGridView(actually it's yiistrap's TbGridView), I created a custom CButtonColumn template with a listen button, everything works fine until I found myself copy this code every where I need a listen button for the table list.

```
array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{listen}{delete}',
        'buttons'=>array(
            'listen'=>array(
                'label'=>'listen',
                'options' => array('class'=>'view headphones'),
                'icon' => 'icon-headphones',
                'url' => '#',
                'visible' => '$data->filename_32',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Is there something I can do to make this little piece of code globally configured? Such as:

```
array(
    'template'=>'{listen}{delete}',
    'buttons'=>array(
        'listen' => 'xxxx.widgets.buttons.Listen',
    )
)
```

Something like this.

Comment: Why don't you use widgets? place the view in the components folder, create appropriate controller and then call the view in a single line of code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can! In your config/main.php, add:

```
'components' => array(
    'widgetFactory' => array(
        'widgets' => array(
            'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn' => array(
                'template'  => '{listen}{delete}',
                'buttons'   => array(
                    'listen' => 'xxxx.widgets.buttons.Listen',
                )
            ),
        )
    )
),
```

This method is mainly used to pre-configure internal widgets though, in situations where you can't control the exact class of the widget that'll be loaded. In your case it looks like you specify the widget classname manually though, so simply overriding the TbButtonColumn widget could be an easier and cleaner solution:

```
class MyTbButtonColumn extends TbButtonColumn {
    public $template = '{listen}{delete}';

    public $buttons = array(
        'listen' => 'xxxx.widgets.buttons.Listen',
    );
}

array(
    'class' => 'MyTbButtonColumn',
),
```

Comment: I see, however, my biggest problem is, how to write `xxxx.widgets.buttons.Listen` exactly? I can't find `CButton` which I can freely extend and create my own "ListenButton" class, it's frustrating, no matter what I do, I just keep duplicating ```array(
                'label'=>'listen',
                'options' => array('class'=>'view headphones'),
                'icon' => 'icon-headphones',
                'url' => '#',
                'visible' => '$data->filename_32',
            ),```

Comment: @ChrisPeng Ah, right, it looks like in Yii1 there is no such thing as a "Button" class, the buttons property is a plain array.

But you could simply define such an array in your MyTbButtonColumn, no?

`class MyTbButtonColumn extends TbButtonColumn {
    public $buttons = array(
        'listen'=>array(
            'label'=>'listen',
            ...
`